# List Split into Consecutive Lists of 2 - Ascending by 1

Tags: python, pandas, list, shift

For the list:

```
list_x=[1,2,3,6,7,8,1,2,6,7]
```

How do you split this into separate lists of 2 elements, that are consectutive and ascending by 1.

**Desired Output**

```
list_a=[1,2]
list_b=[2,3]
list_c=[6,7]
list_d=[7,8]
list_e=[1,2]
list_f=[6,7]
```

Note that 'list_x' can be any length and it is required to split this list into pairs of 2. Each pair is consecutive by plus 1.

This is an attempt:

```
list_a = list_x.ne.shift(fill_value=list_a.iat[0])
```

Thankyou.

Comment: The easy way is `x = list( [a,b] for a,b in zip(list_x[:-1],list_x[1:])`.

Comment: do you actually want them to be called "list_a", "list_b" in the global namespace or can it be a list of lists? if the latter, then `[list_x[i:i+2] for i in range(len(list_x)-1) if list_x[i] + 1 == list_x[i+1]]` will do the trick. Otherwise, you have to nasty things with `globals` or just copy and paste "Desired output" from your question ;)

Comment: Thankyou for these answers - going through hem to understand fully. Also - the lists don't have to be called 'list_a', 'list_b' etc - it was just to illustrate what I was after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For consecutive pairs with consecutive number it is

```
values = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(list_x, list_x[1:]) if a + 1 == b]
print(values)  # [[1, 2], [2, 3], [6, 7], [7, 8], [1, 2], [6, 7]]
```

For all consecutive pairs

```
values = list(zip(list_x, list_x[1:]))
print(values)  # [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 1), (1, 2), (2, 6), (6, 7)]
```

Comment: Awesome - gives exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
list_x = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 6, 7]

list_new = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(list_x, list_x[1:])]
```

It should work alright and is pretty simple. You obtain a list of lists that you want.

Comment: @azro thanks for pointing it out and giving the good answer :)